# Sending response back to the javascript ajax in base64 encoded format

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

i have searched quite a bit but could not find any answer to know if what i'm doing is an acceptable practice. I would rather be told here then be told by the client.

I'm doing a web application with Codeigniter, thus using the MVC pattern.

1. My javascript makes an ajax call to the controller.
2. The controller calls the model to do databased related queries.

Now this is where im unsure.

Model returns database values in this format:

```
$somearray = array('qty'=>'3', 'code'=>'LW12');

$result = array(array('result'=>'1', 'somearray'=>$somearray));

//Now I send the return value to controller in this format

return base64_encode(json_encode($result));
```

My javascript is able to correctly parse the values and use the result. Everything has been working fine, but I'm just concerned about best practice. Pls advice me on this, it would help me alot. Thanks so much.

Comment: return rather than echo, but yes, that's fine to me.

Comment: Hi, Yes, it should be 'return' from model and 'echo' from controller. Fixed that. Thank you, appreciate it.

Comment: Codeigniter does not even remotely related to MVC (aside from abuse in marketing materials).